# multiple condition in select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `SELECT` statement that contains a multiple conditions.

Here is my code for the query:

```
SELECT 
    G.CLOSED_MONTH, EE.BASIC_SALARY, V.EMPLOYEE_NO, G.CLOSED_YEAR
    CASE 
       WHEN ((G.CLOSED_YEAR = YEAR (GETDATE()) AND G.CLOSED_MONTH <= MONTH (GETDATE()) 
          THEN EE.BASIC_SALARY) 
       WHEN (G.CLOSED_YEAR BETWEEN EE.DATE_JOINED AND YEAR (GETDATE()) 
          THEN CASE 
                  WHEN V.ACTIVITY_TYPE = '0'
                     THEN EE.BASIC_SALARY - V.ACTIVITY_VALUE 
                     ELSE EE.BASIC_SALARY + V.ACTIVITY_VALUE 
               END)
       ELSE ((G.CLOSED_YEAR = YEAR (EE.DATE_JOINED) AND G.CLOSED_MONTH >= MONTH (EE.DATE_JOINED)
        THEN CASE WHEN V.ACTIVITY_TYPE = '0'
        THEN EE.BASIC_SALARY - V.ACTIVITY_VALUE 
    ELSE 
        EE.BASIC_SALARY + V.ACTIVITY_VALUE
    END) 
    END AS NEW_BASICSALARY
FROM 
    GENERAL_SPECIFICATION G
JOIN 
    EMPLOYEE_EMPLOYMENT EE ON G.COMPANY_CODE = EE.COMPANY_CODE
JOIN 
    V_EMPLOYEE_PAYACT V ON EE.EMPLOYEE_ID = V.EMPLOYEE_ID
```

When I try to run the query, it keeps on getting error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.

Comment: I want to encourage you​ to try to understand your code line by line, character by character. You would of learned more and this post would of never happened :)

Comment: Your `CASE` code is totally wrong - I couldn't even properly format it..... you have the outermost `CASE`, which has two  `WHEN .. .THEN... ` clauses - but then you suddenly have more `THEN ......` after the final `ELSE` ..... try to **properly format** and indent your code to see which parts belong to which `CASE`, `WHEN` etc. - and you should see you have stuff that just doesn't match up ..,...

Comment: @marc_s is right. Even after you add the comma, it will throw more errors. I would take CodeFlavas advice and work through the errors

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a ',' before the first CASE